# Where is nginx?

Tags: centos, nginx

So uh, I installed nginx on my home network via yum. Now I'd like to change the configuration. However, upon `locate nginx`, it yields no results. None. As if nginx isn't here at all. Meanwhile,

```
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx status
nginx (pid  3235) is running...
```

I'm confused. Where is my nginx configuration? Or my directory for nginx? Or nginx at all?

CentOS5.7, by the way

**EDIT:** Well, I've found nginx. `/etc/nginx`, so why isn't it showing up on my locate? I've ran `updatedb`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most, if not all standard linux software packages keep their configurations in `/etc`. So, I'd check `/etc/nginx`.

Comment: Yeah, I found it there. Finished editing the question right as you posted your answer. :X

Answer (score 2):

As a direct answer: `/etc` is the default location for configuration files, so you can just look there, but that's not always obvious.

The better approach to find onfiguration files for a given package would be to follow these steps (goes for any package):

To find the configuration files of any rpm, you can use `rpm -qc package`

Example:

```
# rpm -qc yum
/etc/logrotate.d/yum
/etc/yum.conf
/etc/yum/version-groups.conf
```

Alternatively, you can use `man` with the name of the executable in question, and look at the related man pages. Any man page with a (5) relates to configuration files. For example, if you `man yum`, and look at the related man pages, you'll find this:

```
SEE ALSO
       pkcon (1)
       yum.conf (5)
       yum-updatesd (8)
       package-cleanup (1)
       repoquery (1)
       yum-complete-transaction (1)
       yumdownloader (1)
       yum-utils (1)
       yum-security (8)
       http://yum.baseurl.org/
       http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
       yum search yum
```

Then you can call `man yum.conf` to call the full documentation on the configuration file options and syntax.

Alternatively, you can also check the `/usr/share/doc/$package_name` for more documentation.

You can also run `makewhatis` and then `man -k <keyword>` to see all man pages relating to a specific keyword.

Comment: My pleasure! I'd rather teach how to fish than blindly give fish away ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the future if you install something w/o verbosity and later want to know what files it installed on an RPM-based distribution, run this:

```
rpm -ql <package name> | sort | uniq
```

Should give you a full list of the files the package installed. Were this a .deb-based (apt) distribution, their equivalent is:

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```